# O loop "enquanto" não analisa dois argumentos no Portugol Studio. Qual aternativa para conseguir o mesmo resultado?

Tags: portugol, portugol-studio

Preciso validar a entrada dessa resposta do usuário. Porém, no código abaixo, o Portugol Studio só reconhece a primeira validação. A segunda (fim != 'n') não é reconhecida, há alguma alternativa para essa validação?

```
escreva("Você gostaria de fazer login no sistema? (Digite s ou n) ")
leia(fim)
enquanto (fim != 's' ou fim != 'n'){
    escreva("Não entendi sua resposta. Você gostaria de fazer login no sistema? (Digite s ou n) ")
    leia(fim)
}
login()
```

Comment: não me parece haver esse limite, já tentou separar as coisas, assim por exemplo? `enquanto ( (fim != 's') ou (fim != 'n') )`. de qualquer forma, não seria um "E" no lugar do "OU"? se quer que a resposta seja S ou N, o operador ai deve ser o  E

Comment: Perfeito! Funcionou aqui. Era a questão lógica mesmo que você levantou. Troquei para o "e". Obrigado!